# user not in wheel group but sudo access possibe

Tags: linux, sudo, root

I have `appuser` user in RHEL OS. This user is not in the `wheel` group.

```
[appuser@NTTAXB01 ~]$ grep wheel /etc/group
wheel:x:10:secadmin,igwuser
[appuser@NTTAXB01 ~]$ getent group wheel
wheel:x:10:secadmin,igwuser
```

But `sudo` access is possible with this user.

```
[appuser@NTTAXB01 ~]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for appuser: 
[root@NTTAXB01 appuser]#
```

How is this possible? Am I missing anything?

Comment: please provide `id appuser` and `grep -v "#" /etc/sudoers` output.

Comment: `$ id appuser`
`uid=1000(appuser) gid=1001(appuser) groups=1001(appuser)`

Comment: so please check `/etc/sudoers`, it may be defined individually for this user.

Comment: Due to word limit restriction, only mentioning the following output from `grep -v "#" /etc/sudoers`. 
`root ALL=(ALL)  ALL
appuser ALL=(ALL) ALL
secadmin ALL=(ALL) ALL

%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments:

`$id appuser`

`uid=1000(appuser) gid=1001(appuser) groups=1001(appuser)`

And from output of `grep -v "#" /etc/sudoers`

this line shows that this user have been added individually.

`appuser ALL=(ALL) ALL`

You can have a look for the configuration of sudo at
[sudeoers file](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/configuring-linux-sudoers-file/)

Comment: Does that mean we can add users to `sudoers` list without adding its group to `sudoers` list, is that?

Comment: yes exactly. you can add either the user or its group.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Comment: BTW, anything we can grab from `id appuser`  here for this problem?

Comment: Yes, for example if `appuser` is also a member of another group let say `sysadmins` and this sysadmin group has been added in sudoers file.

Comment: As per your explanation, `id appuser` should show `wheel` group, right? Have I got it wrong?

Comment: no it's wrong. @PradeepSanjeewa `id appuser` can show for example `sysadmin` group in the group list of the user. and then in sudoers file we can see `%sysadmin ALL=(ALL) ALL` and not `appuser ALL=(ALL) ALL` then again this user will have sudo privilege because the user is in sysadmin group which has sudo privilege. Please have a look at the guide link I put in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Users of `sudo`, and the rights they have, can be individually defined in `/etc/sudoers` and/or in additional files in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory.